# Decorate Xml ClassName on XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, attributes, computer-science, xmlserializer

I need to obtain the following xml:

```
<request id="1">
  <login>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </login>
</request>
```

but the middle xml can change to another type of request like

```
<request id="1">
  <logout />
</request>
```

I tried the following:

```
[XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "request", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Request<T>
{
    [XmlAttributeAttribute(AttributeName = "id", Namespace = "")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public T Content { get; set; }
}

[XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName = "login", AnonymousType = true)]
public class LoginRequest
{
    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "username", Namespace = "")]
    public string Username;

    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "password", Namespace = "")]
    public string Password;
}

[XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName = "logout", AnonymousType = true)]
public class LogoutRequest
{
}
```

But when I serialize the object using

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request<LoginRequest>));
```

I got the following xml:

```
<request id="1">
  <Content>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </Content>
</request>
```

How do I rename the tag Content to login or logout?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know all possible types of request, you can use the [`XmlElement(name, Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cz6bdh5z.aspx) constructor to override the property name for specific types:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "request", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Request
{
    [XmlAttributeAttribute(AttributeName = "id", Namespace = "")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("login", Type = typeof(LoginRequestData))]
    [XmlElement("logout", Type = typeof(LogoutRequestData))]
    public BaseRequestData RequestData { get; set; }

    public TRequestData GetRequestData<TRequestData>() where TRequestData : BaseRequestData
    {
        return RequestData as TRequestData;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseRequestData
{
}

public class LoginRequestData : BaseRequestData
{
    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "username", Namespace = "")]
    public string Username;

    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "password", Namespace = "")]
    public string Password;
}

public class LogoutRequestData : BaseRequestData
{
}

public class SomeUnknownRequestData : BaseRequestData
{
}
```

And, to test:

```
    public static void LoginRequestTest()
    {
        try
        {
            var request1 = new Request() { RequestData = new LoginRequestData() { Username = "foo", Password = "bar" } };
            var request2 = new Request() { RequestData = new LogoutRequestData() };
            var request3 = new Request() { RequestData = new SomeUnknownRequestData() };

            var xml1 = request1.GetXml();
            var xml2 = request2.GetXml();
            try
            {
                var xml3 = request3.GetXml(); // Throws an exception.
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex2)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex2.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, ex.ToString()); // No assert
        }
    }
```

`xml1` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <login>
        <username>foo</username>
        <password>bar</password>
    </login>
</request>
```

while `xml2` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <logout />
</request>
```

Is this what you want?  I eliminated the generic-ness of Request for simplicity.